# How to compare input of date to hard coded date in if statement?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web form and the user inputs a date and I want to compare it against a date to show the availability printed elsewhere and the "show date is the user input and the "2019-05-21" is the data I want to compare to.

```
if (document.getElementById("showDate").value === 2019-05-21 && document.getElementById("selection").value === "Les Miserables")
{
    document.getElementById("displayAva").innerHTML = "65 tickets left";
}
```

Comment: First, please add all the relevant code to your question. That means the HTML as well. Next, you've stated what you want, but haven't really asked a specific question. What does the code you've posted do? Do you get any error messages? What, specific, question do you have?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the user input on #showDate

Comment: Next, understand that `2019-05-21` returns `1993` because to JavaScript, that's just a math expression. To compare a date, you must have another Date type to compare it against. Or, it may be that you have strings that look like dates. In that case, you need to compare a string against another string.

Comment: What does the date type look like if I want to directly compare them instead of creating a date variable?

Comment: It's a value that is stored, so if you want to compare a date, you have to have one, which you can do like this: `new Date(2019-05-21)`

Comment: And with that new Date I could directly compare in an if statement or would I have to declare it earlier on then use it?

Comment: You can do either. But, from the looks of your code, the value you want to check (that comes from `showDate`) isn't a date, it's a string coming from a form field. If that's the case then you need to put quotes around what you have there to compare a string against another string.

Comment: And also make sure that whatever the showDate.value is will definitely be in the same format as the stringified date you're comparing it to.

Answer (score 2):

`2019-05-21` isn't a date.

Just run this code:

```js
console.log(2019-05-21)
```

The output is `1993`, you are doing math operations. Instead, you should use string or [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date).

I don't know what is the value of `document.getElementById("showDate").value`, but if it's string you could simply do:

```
document.getElementById("showDate").value == "2019-05-21"
```

By that way, you would be comparing two strings. If `showDate.value` is exactly `"2019-05-21"` it will return true.

Using `Date` you might do:

```
Date.parse(document.getElementById("showDate").value) == Date.parse("2019-05-21")
```

Or if the other value is already `Date`:

```
document.getElementById("showDate").value.getTime() == Date.parse("2019-05-21")
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById("showDate").value.toUTCString() == new Date("2019-05-21").toTimeString()
```

They are just different ways to compare it, use what you find best for you.